# Whats mistakes with this angular2 unit test setup?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-testing

my application is running good but unit test doesn't work.
[below error throws when i try to npm test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veeUy.jpg)

[image]

**

help me to resolve my issue 
and whats the correct procedure to follow angular2 unit test,
thanks in advance..

- package.json

```html
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "KOC",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "0.0.19",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.0",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.15.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-logger": "^0.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.21",
    "ng2-pagination": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.38",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",

    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "main": "karma-test-shim.js"
}
```

**

- **karma.conf.js**

**

```
// #docregion
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = 'base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase    = 'testing/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'testing/';       // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false},
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    // disabled HtmlReporter; suddenly crashing w/ strange socket error
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],//'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

**

- systemjs.config.js

**

```html
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
            'angular2-highcharts': 'npm:angular2-highcharts',
            'highcharts/highstock.src': 'npm:highcharts/highstock.js',
            'highcharts/highcharts-3d': 'npm:highcharts/highcharts-3d.js',
            'highcharts': 'npm:highcharts',
            'HighchartExporting': 'npm:highcharts/modules/exporting.js',
            'HighchartCSVExporting': 'npm:highcharts/modules/export-csv.js',
            'angular-2-local-storage': 'npm:angular-2-local-storage',
            'angular2-logger': 'npm:angular2-logger',
            'ng2-pagination': 'npm:ng2-pagination',
            "ng2-modal": "node_modules/ng2-modal",

            //'angular2-modal': 'npm:angular2-modal',
            //'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': 'npm:angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-highcharts': {
                main: 'index',
                format: 'cjs',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'highcharts': {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                format: 'cjs'
            },
            'HighchartExporting': {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                format: 'cjs'
            },
            'HighchartCSVExporting': {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                format: 'cjs'
            },
            'angular-2-local-storage': { main: 'dist/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'angular2-logger': { main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'ng2-pagination': {
                main: 'index',
                format: 'cjs',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            "ng2-modal": { "main": "index.js", "defaultExtension": "js" },
            //'angular2-modal': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd' }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**

- app.component.spec.ts

**

```html
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

////////  SPECS  /////////////
describe('AppComponent', function () {
  let de: DebugElement;
  let deClick: DebugElement;
  let comp: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    debugger;
    deClick=fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
  });

  it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined() );

  it('should have expected <h2> text', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const h1 = de.nativeElement;
      expect(h1.innerText).toEqual('Hello Angular');
  });
});
```